# mysql real escape string returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql

Can some one please explain why this simple form doesnt work?

The problem is that when I use `mysql_real_escape_string()` the result are nothing, when I remove it it works perfectly can you please see whats wrong here?

This is the full simple code,

```
<?php

// Loop the post fields
$postFields = array('username', 'password', 'checkSubmission');
$postArray = array();
foreach($postFields as $postVal){
    $postArray[$postVal] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$postVal]);
}
print_r($postArray);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Signin</title>
<head>
</head>
<body><? echo $error;?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="signinForm">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="checkSubmission" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Signin" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

The `print_r()` is empty when I use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
Array ( [username] => [password] => [checkSubmission] => )
```

And this is the `print_r()` without `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
Array ( [username] => thre[password] => werr[checkSubmission] => 1)
```

Thank you for you help

Comment: Can you put the return of "print_r($postArray);" ?

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: Are you connected to your database?  `mysql_real_escape_string` only works if you are connected to the database first.

Comment: Ok, I got it, can't use mysql_real_esape_string with PDO,

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` cannot use connection of `PDO`. If you are using PDO, than use [PDO::quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires an active database connection.

From the php manual:

> A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string()
>   otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is
>   returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection
>   is used.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: I'm using PDO, but this is the answer of my question :)