# How do I update mysql with a variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['aboutme'])) {
$aboutme = $_POST['aboutme'];
$aboutme = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutme);
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `about_me`='" . $aboutme . "' WHERE `username`='" . $usn . "' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, but it does not make it to the proper cell to change it. Here is the text area:

```
<textarea id="aboutme" name="aboutme" rows="4" cols="50"><?php echo "$abme"; ?></textarea>
```

I don't know what is going one here because no errors are coming out of it.

http://gyazo.com/f36f04c014bb229c1be27cc7a9e5072f.png?1363328064

Comment: Have you tried echoing out $aboutme or even the entire query to make sure what you have is what you expect?

Comment: apart from ur issue, You are doing a couple of mistakes like using mysql_real_escape_string and not validating the sql query. anyways can u add ur table schema with ur question

Comment: is your error reporting on ..? as far as I can see nothing is wrong with code ....

Comment: @SomeSillyName That's the problem. Nothing is echoed.

Comment: Where are you putting the echo statement? How about if you echo $_POST? It would help if we could see more of the code.

Comment: @SomeSillyName Echoing $_POST doesn't do anything either. The echo statement comes after.

Comment: `LIMIT` in an update statement?

Comment: @SameSillyName I figured out that $_POST['aboutme'] is not set. So if i remove the if statement, then the query blanks out the cell since there is nothing in it.

Comment: @SomeSillyName I added the form in the OP already.

Comment: I don't see a form, just a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend to switch to mysqli.

[also mysql_real_escape_string() requires an active database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506026/1427338).

So you should connect to the database first or mysql_real_escape_string() will return an empty string

DEBUG :

```
   if (isset($_POST['aboutme'])) {
        $aboutme = $_POST['aboutme'];
        $aboutme = mysql_real_escape_string($aboutme);
        $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `about_me`='" . $aboutme . "' WHERE `username`='" . $usn . "' LIMIT 1";

       mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

}
print_r($query);
```

this will allow you to see the query and trigger will an error if the form is not posted correctlly ( Undefined variable $query).

You can run the query on mysql if it output it to see the result;

Comment: 0 rows affected. ( Query took 0.0002 sec )

Comment: also can you post the resulting query

Comment: I did remove the LIMIT 1 to no avail.